# angular: too many $watch on the page

Tags: angularjs

I use ng-repeat on a  element for displaying a result set. On each row, there is a directive that encapsulates action buttons, which should be visible according to some business rules. This is the view of the directive:

```
<div class="ngCellText grid-actions-cell" ng-class="col.colIndex()">
<span ng-cell-text ng-if="!saving">
    <a class="btn grid-button grid-edit-row btn-primary" href="dm/requests/{{model.id}}/edit" ng-if="(model.status.code === 'UNDE' && userInfo.currentUser === model.assignedTo)  || model.status.code === 'DRAF'" data-tooltip="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
    <a class="btn grid-button  grid-view-row btn-primary" href="dm/requests/{{model.id}}" ng-if="canView()" data-tooltip="View"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
    <a class="btn grid-button  grid-cancel-row btn-danger" ng-if="model.status.code === 'NEW' || (model.status.code === 'UNDE' && userInfo.currentUser === model.assignedTo)" ng-click="cancelRequest()" data-tooltip="Cancel"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>
    <a class="btn grid-button  grid-delete-row btn-danger" ng-if="model.status.code === 'DRAF'" ng-click="deleteRequest()"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" data-tooltip="Delete"></i></a>
    <a class="btn grid-button  grid-reopen-row btn-primary" ng-if="model.status.code === 'CANC' " ng-click="reopenRequest()"><i class="fa fa-undo" data-tooltip="Reopen"></i></a>
    <a class="btn grid-button  grid-reopen-row btn-primary" href="workflow/{{model.id}}/group" ng-if="model.status.code === 'APPR'"><i class="fa fa-flask" data-tooltip="Define Workflow"></i></a>
    <a class="btn grid-button  grid-reopen-row btn-primary" href="workflow/{{model.id}}/edit" ng-if="model.status.code === 'INPR'"><i class="fa fa-flask" data-tooltip="Define Workflow"></i></a>
    <a class="btn grid-button  grid-reopen-row btn-primary" href="dm/requests/{{model.id}}/history"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" data-tooltip="History"></i></a>
</span>
<span ng-cell-text ng-if="saving">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;
</span>
```

This generates 24 watches per line, which ultimately may have an impact on performances. I think it's a high number of watches for such a simple directive. 
Looking at the view, is there a better - more efficient - way to achieve this ?

Comment: There aren't 24 watchers: there is only one watcher for all `{{model.id}}`, and one watcher for each `ngIf` directive. And by the way, 24 primitive comparisons are nothing.

Comment: I've used one-time binding on the 5 model.id using {{::model.id}} and now I've got 19 :) My watch counter is right, but I still have 19. By the way, 19 times the number of rows (potentially 100 is a lot). I don't want to use paging here.

Answer (score 0):

If most of the data presented in your page, once rendered, is immutable so you shouldn't keep watching it for changes, try using the [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) library for improving performance.

So, instead of writing

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in Persons">
        <a ng-href="#/people/{{person.id}}"><img ng-src="{{person.imageUrl}}"></a>
        <a ng-href="#/people/{{person.id}}"><span ng-bind="person.name"></span></a>
        <p ng-class="{'cycled':person.generated}" ng-bind-html-unsafe="person.description"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Use:

```
<ul>
    <li bindonce ng-repeat="person in Persons">
        <a bo-href="'#/people/' + person.id"><img bo-src="person.imageUrl"></a>
        <a bo-href="'#/people/' + person.id" bo-text="person.name"></a>
        <p bo-class="{'cycled':person.generated}" bo-html="person.description"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: [One-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding).

Comment: yes, like i said in my previous reply, I 've used one-time binding on model.id, but I can't do it on the other bindings because they can change anytime.

Comment: Try [ngInfiniteScroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) - a directive that you can use to implement infinite scrolling in your app.